How to know which fields in pydantic model are flagged as 'exclude=True'
I need to create a data object in execution time that maps the schema of a Pydantic v1.10 model that might vary depending on user inputs. This is the example of one of those models:
class MyModel(BaseModel):
    field_1: str = Field(alias="Field 1")
    field_2: str = Field(alias="Field 2")
    field_3: str = Field(alias="Field 3", exclude=True)

I need to exclude fields labeled as exclude=True (this field should not exist in the data object), the problem is that I have no way to know the model that is going to be used until execution time, so the data objects is defined until execution time.
The problem is that I have no way to know what fields of the selected mode are labeled as exclude=True. This info is not provided by MyModel.__fields__ or MyModel.schema().
Is there any way I can get this info?

You can use:
is_exlcuded = getattr(model.__fields__[field_name].field_info, 'exclude')

where field_name is name of the field you are checking.
model_cls.__fields__ is a dict thereby you can dynamically check any field.
It will store information whether a filed is excluded.
